# Error in Android Manifest.. Please

Tags: android, string, manifest

Im beginner for android developing.. I change the android:label text and now it gives me an error on this line on "android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" 
I just add the "title_activity_display_message"

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.celtic.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: what error r u getting ?

Comment: have you declare title_activity_display_message in res/values/string

Comment: have you declare "title_actiity_display_message" in String.xml

Comment: go to the **Resource folder** --> **Value folder ---> string.xml** ---> put the string values what ever you want and call it with **@String/given name in String.xml file**.

Comment: @user3077212 first search it in Google you get so many examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to

res-->values-->strings.xml

and put the following line inside

```
<string name="title_activity_display_message">StackOverflow</string>
```